# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, hide show content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wanting some buttons to pop up divs which where originally hidden on page and came up with this code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#hideshow1').live('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#content1').toggle('show');
        });
    });

     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#hideshow2').live('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#content2').toggle('show');
        });
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#hideshow3').live('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#content3').toggle('show');
        });
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#hideshow4').live('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#content4').toggle('show');
        });
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#hideshow5').live('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('#content5').toggle('show');
        });
    });
});
```

Which works however it causes this error and stops the CKEditor working:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I was wondering if anyone had an alternative more up to date version? Or if they knew a way without jQuery?

Any help is great. Thanks.

Comment: `ready` in `window.onload`. 0_0

Comment: 1) `live()` was deprecated a *long* time ago and you really shouldn't be using it. 2) The error implies that your elements with these click handlers are nested, or the toggling of them raises another click event. Either way the issue is that you're creating an infinite loop, somehow 3) use a single document.ready handler per page. There's no need to put each event handler in its own one and having them all in a window.load is even more redundant. I'd also bet you can DRY this up, but we'd need to see your HTML to help you with that

Comment: It stops *CKEditor* working? Sure it has anything to do with this specific code?

Comment: This is the only jquery on the website, i have however removed all but one document.ready to see if that impacted anything and i'm still getting the error which means the code above could be the only cause for infinite loop.

If i remove this code, or even just remove the 

  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

everything works perfectly